# Ограничение на длину в EditText

Tags: android

Объясните почему не работает ограничение на длину текста в `EditText`

Есть следующее описание:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_column="2"
android:layout_row="3">

...

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:hint=""
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_row="1"

    android:inputType="number"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxLength="2"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Получаю в результате такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Параметры сборки:

```
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 28
```

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь, косяк был у меня, я в ту же ячейку умудрился еще один textEdit запихнуть 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В xml нужно добавить строку:

```
android:maxLength="сколько нужно вводить"
```

вроде у вас стоит этот параметр, но кроме него там присутствует куча параметров которые влияют на поведение поля ввода. Лично я бы вам посоветовал создать новый `edittext` и в нем попробовать использовать не все параметры сразу, а по очереди. Вообще во всех источниках говорят что нужно добавлять только этот атрибут для поля ввода.

Но я могу ошибаться.

Answer (score 1):

Есть [мнение 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31693042/5330439) и [мнение 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33401067/5330439), что eсли вы используете InputFilter для edittext, то maxLength не будет работать. Если вы добавляете InputFilter  вручную, свойство xml переопределяется.

Можно воспользоваться следующим [советом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37922370/5330439)

```
month.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilterMinMax("0", "12"), new InputFilter.LengthFilter(2)});
```

Comment: Не хотелось бы программно это делать